# DISTINCT in mysql query removing the records from resultset

Tags: mysql

**DISTINCT** in mysql query removing the records from resultset

I have three tables

```
TBL1       TBL2         TBL3
----       ------       --------    
tbl1_id    tbl2_id      tbl3_id                       
cid        fkcid        fkcid
           fktbl1_id    fktbl2_id
```

I have query to get records of TBL3

```
select distinct tbl3.* from TBL3 tbl3 
inner join TBL2 tbl2 on tbl2.tbl2_id = tbl3.fktbl2_id and tbl2.fkcid = tbl3.fkcid 
inner join TBL1 tbl1 on tbl1.tbl1_id = tbl2.fktbl1_id and tbl2.fkcid = tbl1.cid;
```

This query gives me around 1000 records.

But when I **removes distinct from query** it gives me around 1100 records.
There is no duplicate records in table.Also I confirmed that these extra 100 are not duplicate.Please note That these extra 100 records are not found in **query with distinct keyword**.

Why this query is behaving unexpectedly.Please help me to understand more clearly and correct me if i am making mistake.
Thank you

Comment: You probably have a one-to-many relationship that is happening when you join on the other tables.  Meaning your `Tbl3` key is appearing multiple times in either `Tbl1` or `Tbl2`.  The DISTINCT is removing these _duplicates_, but they aren't actually duplicates.  You could see the data if you included all data from all tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple records in tbl1 or tbl2 that map to the same tbl3, and since you're only selecting tbl3.* in your output, DISTINCT removes the duplication.    To instead find what the duplicates are, remove the DISTINCT, add a COUNT(*) to the SELECT clause, and add at the end a GROUP BY and HAVING, such as:

```
select tbl3.*, count(*) 
from TBL3 tbl3  
inner join TBL2 tbl2 on tbl2.tbl2_id = tbl3.fktbl2_id and tbl2.fkcid = tbl3.fkcid  
inner join TBL1 tbl1 on tbl1.tbl1_id = tbl2.fktbl1_id and tbl2.fkcid = tbl1.cid 
group by tbl3.tbl3_id, tbl3.fkcid, tbl3.fktbl2_id having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: it is giving zero records.That means no duplicate.