# what will DISTINCT alias.* do in mysql select clause

Tags: mysql

I have query in MySQL which is fetching thousands of records from table A.
Table A does not have any duplicate row.

I want to understand what will be the behavior of following distinct query

```
select distinct alias.* from table A alias;
```

on what column it will apply distinct?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique key (or primary key) on that table, or simply that there are no duplicates, then nothing. Every single row in your result set will be unique already.

The MySQL documentation for the [`SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) points out that `DISTINCT` (or the synonym, `DISTINCTROW`) mentions that `DISTINCT` simply removes duplicate rows fromt he result set.

Comment: Okay!! I have primary in my table `A` when I execute above query in result I get only 98 but I suppose to get 100 records, when I remove `distinct` it gives 100 results.

Comment: @oomph then you have 2 rows that are somehow duplicates of rows in the rest of your table. You'd have to properly profile your data to see where.

Comment: How that two records gonna be duplicate. I have primary key in table which is `AI`.

Comment: Has it always been AI? Try running `SELECT DISTINCT alias.id FROM table_a alias` and seeing if it returns 100 rows. I'm a little wary of the fact that you might have oversimplified your example `SELECT` statement in your question and you're missing something obvious. Could we see a more accurate `SELECT` statement that you're performing?

Comment: my detailed problem is explained in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570021/distinct-in-mysql-query-removing-the-records-from-resultset/25570626#25570626

Comment: As the other answer states you likely have a one to many relationship. Try `SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.*, tbl3.* FROM [All your tables joined here]` and then have a proper look at your data. We can't profile your data for you.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` selects an unique *record*, not a unique *field* value.

In this query, as @ydaetskcoR said, if you have a primary key `DISTINCT` is useless.

If you don't, it will just select only one occurence of your duplicate records.

Comment: Okay!! I have primary in my table A when I execute above query in result I get only 98 but I suppose to get 100 records, when I remove distinct it gives 100 results